# How to change the table layout when using datalist?

Tags: asp.net, .net, css, datalist

How to change the table layout when using datalist. Below is the aspx i am using to populate the data, but i get the result like shown in Example 1. There is not continuation of showing the data due to the table layout ? How can achieve to show the result as shown in example 2 ?

I am in need of using the datalist since I am using repeatcolumn which is not available in repeater.

[image]

Aspx :

```
<asp:DataList ID="dl_Groups" RepeatColumns="2"  runat="server" 
    OnItemDataBound="dl_Groups_ItemDataBound" RepeatDirection="vertical" 
    ShowFooter="False" ShowHeader="False">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk_Group" Text='<%# Eval("category_type") %>' 
            Value='<%# Eval("service_type_category_id") %>' onclick="OnGroupClick" />
       <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="chkServiceType" Style="padding-left: 20px" 
            DataValueField="ServiceTypeID" DataTextField="Name" EnableViewState="true">
       </asp:CheckBoxList>
       <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you gone through these properties of the CheckBoxList

```
  RepeatColumns="2"
  RepeatDirection="Vertical"
  RepeatLayout="Table"
```

These may be helpful to you.

You may also take benefit of `css`
As follows

```
#chkServiceType tr{
display:inline-block;
margin-right:20px;
} ​

#chkServiceType tr label{
margin-left:5px;
}
```

Comment: There is no change of layout after i tried your method. The layout is still like Example 1. Is there any other way ?